# How to return a plain text string back to browser in lift views?

Tags: scala, view, lift, plaintext

I would like to return plain-text back to browser in a lift view like this:

```
import scala.xml.Text    
def csv_export_status_check: NodeSeq = {
    Text("my text")
}
```

But the "my text" just does not show at all.

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: It should work. Do you have any link to the repository, I could take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the following, and it worked:

```
def render =
  xml.Text("aoeu")
```

Actually, your version should work as well - maybe there is some other problem?

Comment: This seems to be the right solution already. But mine keeps on giving me an empty page. I think it's because of something else. Debugging...

Comment: It turned out to be a version bug.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need, here's a solution that returns just plain text:

```
  serve {
    case rq@ Req("my"::"stuff"::Nil, suffix, PostRequest) => processMyRequest()
  }

  def response(txt: String) = InMemoryResponse(txt.getBytes, Nil, Nil, 200)

  def processMyRequest(): () => Box[LiftResponse] = {
    Full(response("my text"))
  }
```